# varnish is unable to take hold of port 80 on ec2 machine

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to run varnish in a docker container in an ec2 instance.
I tried doing the same in my local and it worked fine. but it keep on giving error:
**Error: Could not get socket :80: Permission denied**

My vcl looks like:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
 .host = "x.y.z.y";
 .port = "8090";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "BAN") {
        ban("obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host + " && obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url);
        return(synth(200, "Banned added"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Store URL and HOST in the cached response.
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Prevent the client from seeing these additional headers.
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
sub vcl_deliver {
    # Prevent the client from seeing these additional headers.
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
```

and there is no process running on 80 port

Comment: The VCL file doesn't really matter too much in this case. What I really need is the mechanism you use to launch the `docker run` command. If this is done via Systemd, I'd like to see your Systemd unit file. Accessing port 80 usually requires root permissions, so I'd like to see how you start the container within the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

To access 80 port requires root permission, try to run docker command from root user or add your user to docker group.